# E2E test multiple custom elements by id

Tags: javascript, aurelia, e2e-testing

**Question:** How would you E2E test a SPA with many custom elements which are created multiple times and able to retrieve them by unqiue ID?

The problem we have is to unique identify the custom elements. Thus, you can't place an id inside the custom element like this:

```
<customelement id="MyCustomElement"></customelement>
```

because as you would instantiate the custom element multiple times the id will be added twice to the DOM.

Aurelia uses protractor as E2E test tooling. Including the Aurelia flavoured locator to retrieve/check value.bind="VMproperty" syntax. The elment(by.valueBind("VMproperty")) won't work for multiple custom elements which have the VMProperty.

We're thinking in creating somekind of breadcrumb which includes the parent id, creating an unique ID for that specific custom element.

I'm sure people would be using Aurelia for larger projects/sites and require proper E2E testing. The example on Aurelia HUB: http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/testing/latest/end-to-end-testing/5 is fine for initial setup, but doesnt state in how to E2E test mulitple custom elements.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you could walk down to the custom element from the parent element with `$('#parentID customelement')` if there's just one of them.

If you have multiple custom elements within the parent, you can just get all of them with `$('#parentID').$$('customelement')` and iterate through the ElementArrayFinder.

If you don't have to worry about custom elements within other parent elements, you could even just use `$$('customelement')` to grab all of them in an ElementArrayFinder.

To go over each element in the ElementArrayFinder when you don't know the order, I tend to go two ways.

The first way filters the ElementArrayFinder down to the ElementFinder you want:

```
var item = $$('.someclass').filter((elem)=>{
    return elem.isWhatIWant(); //chose any qualifier that returns a boolean
}).first();
expect(item.isWhatIWant()).toBeTruthy();
```

The second way goes over and checks each element:

```
$$('.someclass').each((elem)=>{
    expect(elem.isWhatIWant()).toBeTruthy();
})
```

I use the second way more often, since you can always add qualifiers within the each to determine which elements should be checked, but the first way can be better if you want to save the ElementFinder for later use.

Comment: mmm, how would you distinguish 2 customelements from within a parent? As your 2nd example, would probably fetch the first one? What if you want to test the 2nd customelement?
 
If both have an unique ID, then you can test the content for the first customelement and the 2nd customelement.

Comment: the $$ means that it is retrieving all of the custom elements as a ElementArrayFinder object. If you know the order, you can get a specific customelement with x.get(index), when the x is your ElementArrayFinder. If you don't know the order, you can use a x.then() call to iterate on the retrieved array of ElementFinders.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification about the $$ usage and the ElementArrayFinder. Lets say if you don't know the order of customelements in the ElementArrayFinder. You still need to check somehow that you are compare/check the right customelement.
I have the feeling that I should add something unique to my customelements on generation and have the ability to filter to each customelement and test it. How are other SPA E2E tested? webapp wide unique id?

Comment: I added some more to my answer. As far as a unique id for each customelement, it depends on your implementation. There should be some marker to let you know what to test for each customelement, but that can usually be determined by their class or position in the DOM.